# Combining character with combining mark makes it appear shifted to the right

Tags: swift, unicode

I'm combining some characters with unicode combining marks. Some marks when presented in labels, however appear shifted to the right, this is not the actual example but let's say I were to combine `A` and `˚`. Instead of having Å, i have A˚. If I copy the text and paste it somewhere else, the character appears perfect (Å).

To combine the characters I use a method that does this:

```swift
Character("\(character)\(mark)")
```

Where character would be a letter and mark an accent or another combining mark.

I read that this may happen because some fonts don't support certain characters. The font I use for my labels where I display the combined stuff is the systemFont.

Why is this happening? How can I prevent combined characters from being shifted to the right?

Comment: You'll need to give an actual example. When you say "in labels" what do you mean? The example you've given here uses RING ABOVE (U+02DA), which is not a combining mark. You likely mean COMBINING RING ABOVE (U+030A). It's possible you know that, and that you've just shown the wrong character in your example, but we can't guess what you're doing in your real code. I expect your real code is different since if you made the mistake your example describes, it would crash. (Å is an extremely well-supported glyph, so I doubt this is font related.)

Comment: Your mark is `˚` U+02DA (UTF-8 `0xCB,0x9A`) ModifierSymbol _Ring Above_. Use another: `̊` U+030A (UTF-8 `0xCC,0x8A`) NonSpacingMark _Combining Ring Above_.